# How do I find the days between two dates in JavaScript or jQuery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, date-range

I am using jQuery datepicker. In my application, I have `startDate` and `endDate` date ranges.

If my date range is less than a week(7 days), I need to disable some day textbox's. Please see the image below

**Expected output:**
[image: Expected Output]

I can able to get the number of days difference between to dates like this;

```
var startDate = $('#startDate').datepicker('getDate');
var endDate = $('#endDate').datepicker('getDate');
//find difference between start and end date
var noOfDays = Math.ceil((startDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

If `noOfDays` is less than 7 days, I need to disable the day textbox according to the date range. For that I need list days between date ranges.

According to my example image `Mon` and `Sun` should be disabled.

`['Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat']` or corresponding UTC day values `['1','2','3','4','5']` should be enabled.

Can anyone guide me to get day values?

Comment: var startDate = $('#startDate').datepicker('getDate');
var endDate = $('#endDate').datepicker('getDate');
var diffDays = endDate.getDate() - startDate.getDate();
alert(diffDays);

Comment: @prakashtank : I can find difference of days. But I need days occurrence between the date ranges like `['Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :
month is start from 0.

```
var from = new Date(2016, 11, 29);
var to = new Date(2016, 11, 31);
var DAYS = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tu', 'Wed', 'Th', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

var d = from;
while (d <= to) {
    alert(DAYS[d.getDay()]);
    d = new Date(d.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
}
```